# connection to oracle db gives System.TypeInitializationException' in Oracle.DataAccess.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, .net-core

I trying to connect to an database in a little console application it works. but now i am making a restfull api for school but i am stuck on a **runtime error**:

> System.TypeInitializationException' in Oracle.DataAccess.dll

[my code end exception in my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLe5V.png)

I tried a lot. checked if the version are correct it is al set up good i think. i am using

```
    [HttpPost("InsertKlok")]
    public IActionResult InsertKlok(Klok klkregd)
    {
        string constr = "Data Source=MydataSource;User Id=MyuserId;Password=Mypassword;";
        var query = "Insert INTO KLOK(KLOK_ID, REDEN,INUIT) VALUES(" + klkregd.Klok_Id + ",'" + klkregd.Reden + "','" + klkregd.InUit + "')";
        try
        {
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(constr);
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Record inserted");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        return Ok(klkregd);
    }

    [Route("klok/")]
    [HttpPost("AddKlok")]
    public JsonResult AddKlok(Klok klkregd)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In registerStudent");
        KlokRegistratieAntwoord klkregdreply = new KlokRegistratieAntwoord();
        KlokRegistratie.getInstance().Add(klkregd);
        klkregdreply.Klok_Id = klkregdreply.Klok_Id;
        klkregdreply.Reden = klkregdreply.Reden;
        klkregdreply.InUit = klkregdreply.InUit;

        return Json(klkregdreply);
    }
}
```

}
`

In my console application i have same code and file for oracle connection but its not working here pls can someone help me

Comment: `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` depends on *Oracle client*, *.Net version* and *architecture* (e.g. in can be `Oracle client 12i, x86 for .Net 3.5` if anything don't match you can well have type initialization error) Try https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/ instead; quotation: "ODP.NET, Managed Driver is a **100% native .NET code driver**. *No additional* Oracle Client software is required to be installed to connect to Oracle Database"

Comment: Instead of concatenated strings you should better use prepared statements with bind parameters, see [Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleParameterClass.htm#ODPNT1771)

Comment: Did you install the ODP.NET provider? Is it the same architecture (i.e. 32-bit vs. 64-bit) as your application?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko first of all thanks for your commen <3. Can you give me an example with configuration for example wich .net framework i can use with oracle product 11?

Comment: @pieterjanse: you can use *any* .Net Framework with `Oracle 11i`, however, if insist on `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` you have to get the right one (from https://www.oracle.com/Downloads/), taking into account architecture (x86 or AI64), .Net version (`1`, `2`, `4`) and Oracle Client version. In case of `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` you don't have find out the right version; `ManagedDataAccess` would do for any architecture, client, .net combination

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i use managedDataAcces.dll now but gives the same error: 
Package 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 19.3.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: @pieterjanse: I see; you use **.net Core**, that's why you want `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core` see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/ and https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/ODPNET_Core_get_started/index.html

Comment: @DmitryBychenko And can i use the same code if i use the nuget oracle.managedDataAcces

Comment: @DmitryBychenko It works!!  I use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core now and it works:) thanks a lot.

Comment: @pieterjanse: You are welcome! Next time, please, do not forget to specify `.net-core` and you'll get the answer earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use **.net core** you can try `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core` instead of 
`Oracle.DataAccess`; quotation:

> Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET) Core is an ADO.NET driver that
>   provides fast data access from Microsoft **.NET Core** clients to Oracle
>   databases. ODP.NET Core consists of a single **100% managed code**
>   dynamic-link library

(**bold** is mine). You can get the assembly via *Nuget*:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/

Please, have a look at the *tutorial* from Oracle as well:

https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/ODPNET_Core_get_started/index.html